# How do you increase the amount of attack hits?

Tags: bravely-default

At the moment, in chapter 4, with a job like Ninja or Hunter, i can hit 10-11 times with each attack.
I have notice that if i change to a job with few levels, the amount of hits are capped.
Dows anyone know how this works?

There is a skill that doubles the number of hits. What is the maximum number of hits?

Answer (score 2):

Your possible hit count is determined by your agility and your job and its level. You can also temporarily raise the hit count by some special skills, mainly from daggers. You get 1 base hit, after that you get 1 additional hit for every 10 agility and then you get more hits depending on your job and job level - casters get the least; ninja, thieves and rangers the most (7 extra hits at job level 14, I think).

After that, you still can miss on some attacks, which brings your actual hit count down, so Aim (and dexterity) comes into play, too.

As for the maximum number of hits, it should be 32 as said in the description of ninja's Frenetic Fighting (the skill you mention).

Comment: You forgot to mention the Ninja's Ikkikasei ability.